# C# . net Countdown timer alignment issue

Tags: c#, .net, countdown

I have a silly little problem, so i created a countdown timer using visual studio 2015.

http://puu.sh/k2l7z/d18cda8a50.png
This is basically how it looks but here is my problem.

http://puu.sh/k2l8V/98d82feccc.png
When the timer goes below 10 the number leaves a gap where the 0 would usually be, how could i move the 8 over to where the 0 is usually? So it doesn't have a big gap when counting down?

or adding a 0 so it shows 08:41 instead of 8  : 41

Thanks

```
private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = s - 1;

        if (s == -1)
        {
            m = m - 1;
            s = 59;
        }

        if (m == 0 && s == 0)
        {
            count.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Countdown Finished");
        }
        string mm = Convert.ToString(m);
        string ss = Convert.ToString(s);

        mn_label.Text = mm;
        se_label.Text = ss;
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m = Convert.ToInt32(mn_label.Text);
        s = Convert.ToInt32(se_label.Text);
        count.Start();
    }
```

Comment: It would be easy if you show the code that outputs your value.

Comment: added code to the post

Comment: It's possible this is happening due to the text align property on the label (long time since I've done stuff with forms, but I'm sure there's a similar property there)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, then doing the following should be enough.

Instead of:

```
string mm = Convert.ToString(m);
string ss = Convert.ToString(s);
```

Write:

```
string mm = m.ToString("00"); 
string ss = s.ToString("00");
```